# javafx drag and drop not able to drop in another application, can from a swing wrapper

Tags: java, swing, javafx, drag-and-drop

Here is a sample application, which allows you to drag and drop some text into other areas.

One application I want to drop into allows the drop from swing but not from JavaFX.

If the JavaFX is in a JFXPanel and a Swing JFrame, it drops fine.
If it's just pure JavaFX in a Stage, it has the 'no entry' logo and doesn't accept the drop.

Other applications allow or block both.  But this one application accepts the drop from JFrame but not Stage, the actual Label component etc is the same.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.swing.*;

public class DragViewExample extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TextField tf = new TextField("Copied Text");

    tf.setOnDragDetected(e -> {
        Dragboard db = tf.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.COPY);
        db.setDragView(new Text(tf.getText()).snapshot(null, null), e.getX(), e.getY());
        ClipboardContent cc = new ClipboardContent();
        cc.putString(tf.getText());
        db.setContent(cc);
    });

    tf.setOnDragDropped(event -> {
        System.out.println("dropped");
    });

    tf.setOnDragDone(event -> {
        System.out.println("done");
    });

    //FULL JAVAFX
    Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(new HBox(10, tf)), 350, 75);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    //JAVAFX INSIDE SWING
//        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
//        JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
//        Scene swingscene = new Scene(new StackPane(new HBox(10, tf)), 350, 75);
//        fxPanel.setScene(swingscene);
//        frame.setContentPane(fxPanel);
//        frame.pack();
//        frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work cause you have not implemented on `onDragOver`:
The correct way to do the drag and drop here is(**where source is the textField**):

```
source.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        /* drag was detected, start a drag-and-drop gesture*/
        /* allow any transfer mode */
        Dragboard db = source.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);

        /* Put a string on a dragboard */
        ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();          
        content.putString(source.getText());
        db.setDragView(new Text(tf.getText()).snapshot(null, null), e.getX(), e.getY());
        db.setContent(content);

        event.consume();
    }
});


target.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
    public void handle(DragEvent event) {
        /* data is dragged over the target */

        if (event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
            /* allow for both copying and moving, whatever user chooses */
            event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
        }

        event.consume();
    }
});
```

> For a full answer follow the official oracle tutorial

(http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/drag_drop/jfxpub-drag_drop.htm)

Comment: Hi Thanks, for the quick response.
Maybe I wasn't clear in the post, but the target is not in my application.

It is a 3rd party application, which accepts the drop.  So I do not have the target to setOnDragOver.

The 3rd part application accepts it from the JFXPanel/JFrame, but not from the Stage.

Comment: @user486415 If you are implementing right the code from the JavaFX application then the problem is in the target application.Where is the code from the target application?Maybe it is not accepting the  `TransferMode.Copy` . Give a try the code i have added and let me know what it happens...

Comment: I do not have the code for the target application.
It accepts the TransferMode.COPY for the above code example where I have it in a JFrame, but not when it's in a Stage.  I can't see any real difference in debugging

Comment: @user486415 What operating System are you using?Also dragging the text from the Stage to a text editor,for example `notepad` it works?